# Fracture a plane with the voronoi pattern (cell fracture flat geometry issue)

Tags: modeling, modifiers, procedural, cell-fracture

I need to fracture a 2D plane on pieces (I need to keep 'em flat). When I apply cell fracture, the fractured pieces become solid (they are not flat anymore). How can I overcome the issue? I don't mind using cell fracture or any other way to fracture the geometry. I just need to keep it flat and clean.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could join all the pieces as one geometry, then view from the side and remove the bottom half of the vertices. After that maybe use some kind of separate by loose parts option to bring it back to individual pieces.